# How to compare Rails Form Parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, parameters

So I am making a program that has a script "Set of Steps to complete a Task" that can be applicable to all stores or only a select few. The all stores option is a boolean value that gets stored with the script. What I would like that to do is when you select "Yes" to all stores it should remove all stores associated with that script if there are any. The script and store tables have a HABTM relationship. The question is how do I check inside a parameter to see if the value of all_stores is true? I have tried a few things and it seems to just ignore the if statement to compare the all stores parameter to true

**Script Controller**

```
  def update
    params[:script][:store_ids] ||= []
    if params[:script][:all_stores] == true
      params[:script][:store_ids] = []
    end
    @script = Script.find(params[:id])
    if @script.update_attributes(params[:script])
      flash[:notice] = 'Script was successfully updated'
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
    else
      @categories = category_search
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end
```

**Script Edit View**

```
<%= form_for(:script, :url => {:action => 'update', :id =>@script.id}) do |f| %>
    <div id="script_form_visibility">
        <div class="issue_section_header" align="center">Visibility</div>
        <div class="line-break"></div>
        <div class="standardText"><span class="boldText">All Stores:</span> <%=f.radio_button(:all_stores, true)%> Yes <%=f.radio_button(:all_stores, false)%> No</div>
        <br/>
        <div class="issue_section_header" align="center">Stores</div>
        <div class="line-break"></div>
        <div class="standardText">
            <%@stores.each do |store|%>
                <%= check_box_tag 'script[store_ids][]', store.id, @script.store_ids.include?(store.id), :id => dom_id(store) %>
                <%= label_tag dom_id(store), store.name, :class => "check_box_label" %><br/>
            <%end%>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="script_form">
        <div class="boldText"><%= f.label :name %></div>
        <div><%=f.text_field :name, :size => '94', :maxlength => '70'%></div>
        <div>
            <table width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td class="boldText"><%= f.label :category_id, "Category" %></td>
                    <td class="boldText" align="right">Show ID Required Field</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="standardText"><%=f.select(:category_id, @categories.collect {|c| [c.name, c.id]}, :selected => session[:admin_category])%></td>
                    <td class="standardText" align="right"><%=f.radio_button(:require_id, true)%> Yes <%=f.radio_button(:require_id, false)%> No</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="boldText"><%= f.label :task %></div>
        <div><%= f.text_area(:task, :size => "68x20") %></div>
        <div class="boldText"><%= f.label :expected_results, "Expected Results" %></div>
        <div><%= f.text_area(:expected_results, :size => "68x20") %></div>
        <div align="center"><%= f.submit "Update Script" %></div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems like this are easily solved in the rails debugger.  Fire it up and then set a breakpoint at this line:

```
if params[:script][:all_stores] == true
```

When you reach the breakpoint example the contents of your params hash

```
(rdb:3) p params[:script][:all_stores]
```

This will tell you why your code isn't behaving as expected.

Comment: Thank you it should have been if params[:script][:all_stores] == "true"